# SSH asks password when logging from third computer

Tags: ssh

I have 3 systems: A, B, C.

I CAN login passwordless in this combination:

- A-B
- A-C

But when i try to do **A-B-C**, it requests a password. I generated a new pair of keys for connecting B-C.

Dont know what can be wrong. Any tips? Thanks!

Edit: ran `sshd` in debug mode on C:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 38: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa xxxx
debug1: private host key #1: xxx
debug1: private host key #2: xxxx
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.2 port 53084 on 192.168.1.3 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 107/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user pi service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
reprocess config line 38: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
debug1: PAM: initializing for "pi"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.2"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
```

Comment: Needs more verbosity. Try `-vvv` instead of `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSH agent forward enabling on your SSH client?

Example for GitHub but applies in general to SSH clients: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

More detailed explanation of SSH agent forwarding: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html